# How can I check whether an enum equals any of several different values?

Tags: delphi, enums

In the `Data.DB` unit, the following enum is declared:

```
TFieldType = (ftUnknown, ftString, ftSmallint, ftInteger, ftWord, ftBoolean, ftFloat, ...)
```

I need to determine if the `DataType` of a field in a search grid is an integer, string, float, date, blob, etc.

Integer should be any type that can be used as an integer, like `ftSmallint`, `ftInteger`, `ftWord`, etc.

Is there a shorter way to do this than the following?

```
if (Field.DataType = ftInteger) or (Field.DataType = ftSmallint) or (Field.DataType = ftWord) then Result := ftInteger;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this

```
if Field.DataType in [ftInteger, ftSmallInt, ftWord] then ...
```

Also, you could define a set type as a `set of TFieldType` and use a variable of that type to store the fieldtypes you're looking for and then use `if Field.DataType in ...` on that.

Comment: It also can use ORD to get the position in the enumeration.

Comment: I will define set of TFieldType and use it. I was hoping such a types exists somewhere.

Comment: I just searched the D7 source and the only `set of TFieldType` declaration I found was the `BinaryDataTypes` one in RecError.Pas.

Comment: I would use a constant instead of a variable:  `const IntegerFields = [ftInteger, ftSmallInt, ftWord]; ... if Field.DataType in IntegerFields then ...`

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Thanks.  I was coming at the problem from a slightly different direction, namely how to change the matched type(s) with the smallest possible code change.

Answer (score 1):

```
case Field.DataType of
        ftUnknown, ftVariant   : Result:= ftVariant;
        ftWideString, ftString : Result:= ftString;
        ftAutoInc, ftLargeint,ftWord, ftInteger, ftSmallint  : Result:= ftInteger;
        ftBoolean              : Result:= ftBoolean;
        ftFMTBcd               : Result:= ftFMTBcd;
        ftBCD                  : Result:= ftBCD;
        ftFloat, ftCurrency    : Result:= ftFloat;
        ftTime, ftDateTime, ftDate: Result:= ftDateTime;
        ftGraphic, ftBlob, ftMemo, ftFmtMemo: Result:= ftBlob;
      end;
```